# Easily review large set of short sound files

Tags: itunes, audio

I have a large set of mp3s that I need to listen to and evaluate. If I add them to iTunes, it wants to play them consecutively without stopping. I need to listen (once), think, possibly replay, etc., until I'm ready to go onto the next.

I've also tried VLC. It also (by default) wants to play as a playlist w/o stopping. It does let you loop each file, but then you have to listen to it looping rather than hear it as a one-shot (which is how it would be used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Quick Look.
iTunes will never know or care you played them, won't add them to its content.

Just drop all the files into a single flat folder *[or any hierarchy you like]*, select the first one, hit the Space bar.
That one file will play as a one-shot.
Use the arrow keys to switch the currently-selected file, that will play. *[if you have a nested hierarchy, all 4 arrow keys come into play to navigate around, column view is easiest]*
Replay is either drag the play position marker back to the beginning, or quickly arrow up/down to select another file & back - easy to do before it starts to play the other file.

When you're done, Space bar again will kill the Quick Look window.

Works with anything iTunes can play, aif, wav, mp3, aac etc

Downside is you can't touch any other file or folder whilst it's playing - but you can use other apps & switch between, so long as you don't touch the Finder itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In iTunes, if you uncheck the checkbox next to each song, you can play one at a time.